# mapping a nested array in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to dynamically load resume information from a JSON file into a React component.  I am able to get the company, title, and timeframe to load properly, but when I try to get the responsibilities for the position to load I keep getting an error.

The JSON is designed similar to:

```
[
{
  "company": "Company Name",
  "title": ["Position 1", "Position 2"],
  "time": ["January 2017 - Present", "January 2016 - December 2017"],
  "responsibilities": [["Responsibility 1", "responsibility 2", "responsibility 3"],["Thing 1","thing 2", "thing 3"]]
  },
]
```

The index of each array corresponds to the same information. IE index 0 is the same title, timeframe and responsibilities.

I have tried several different variations of trying to map into the internal arrays but keep getting various errors

```
      return (
        <div className='work'>
          {Data.map(({company, title, time, responsibilities, resp}, index)=>
            <div>
              <h1>{company}</h1>
              {title.map((title, index)=>
                <div key={index}>
                  <h2>{title}</h2>
                  <h3>{time[index]}</h3>
                  {responsibilities.map((respArr)=>
                  <ul key={index}>
                    {respArr.map(resp =>
                    <li>{resp}</li>
                    )}
                  </ul>
                  )}
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          )}
```

The error I am receiving with this code is

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
(anonymous function)
src/components/exp.js:14
  11 | {title.map((title, index)=>
  12 |   <div key={index}>
  13 |     <h2>{title}</h2>
> 14 |     <h3>{time[index]}</h3>
     | ^  15 |     {responsibilities.map((respArr)=>
  16 |     <ul key={index}>
  17 |       {respArr.map(resp =>
```

If I remove the section with the responsibilities.map it populates the company, title, and timeframe for the position correctly but I have not been able to also add a UL with a li for each responsibility under each title / timeframe.

The intended output is

```
Company
Position 1
January 2017 - Present
-Responsibility 1
-Responsibility 2
-Responsibility 3

Position 2
January 2016 - December 2017
-Thing1
-Thing2
-Thing3
```

Comment: Do you have hard-coded data? What is the source of the data?

Comment: Your code is seems to be fine - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mp9x4m. Might be the issue with your Data source.

Comment: Similar to what @ravibagul91 is saying, please note your code is not 100% reproducible, as the data isn't part of it

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I did go back to my data and make some edits and that helped however It still is not quite right.  Instead of the first array of responsibilities matching up with the first title and the second array with the second title, both arrays of responsibilities are falling under both titles.  Any idea where I am going wrong?  Intended output updated above.

Answer (score 0):

You should bring your responsibilities out of your title.map like this

```
  return (
    <div className='work'>
      {Data.map(({company, title, time, responsibilities, resp}, index)=>
        <div>
          <h1>{company}</h1>
          {title.map((title, index)=>
            <div key={index}>
              <h2>{title}</h2>
              <h3>{time[index]}</h3>
            </div>
          )}
          {responsibilities.map((respArr)=>
            <ul key={index}>
              {respArr.map(resp =>
              <li>{resp}</li>
              )}
            </ul>
            )}
        </div>
      )}
```

Comment: No. Code is fine.

Comment: Why is the OP's code wrong?
Your suggestion will change the order and the amount of times `responsibilities` is printed

Answer (score 0):

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const sampleData = [{
      "company": "Company Name",
      "title": ["Position 1", "Position 2"],
      "time": ["January 2017 - Present", "January 2016 - December 2017"],
      "responsibilities": [
        ["Responsibility 1", "responsibility 2", "responsibility 3"],
        ["Thing 1", "thing 2", "thing 3"]
      ]
    }]
   return (
      <div className="work">
        {sampleData.map(({
          company, title, time, responsibilities, resp,
        }, index) => (
          <div>
            <h1>{company}</h1>
            {title.map((title, index) => (
              <div key={index}>
                <h2>{title}</h2>
                <h3>{time[index]}</h3>
              </div>
            ))}
            {responsibilities.map(respArr => (
              <ul key={index}>
                {respArr.map(resp => <li>{resp}</li>)}
              </ul>
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    )}
    }

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  While this is very close it is not exactly what I was hoping for.  I have updated my original post for the intended output but essentially I am hoping to get the Timeframe and responsibilities that correspond to each title to line up under each title.  Any additional help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I was able to come up with.  This does give the output I was looking for, thank you all so much for your help.

```
return (
        <div className='work'>
          {Data.map(({company, title, time, responsibilities, resp})=>
            <div>
              <h1>{company}</h1>
              {title.map((title, index)=>
                <div key={index}>
                  <h2>{title}</h2>
                  <h3>{time[index]}</h3>
                  {responsibilities[index].map((resp)=>
                    <ul>
                      <li >{resp}</li>
                    </ul>
                  )}
                  </div>
              )}
            </div>
            )} 
         </div>
```